# How to customise AlexNet for 3 classes instead of 1000?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using an AlexNet from [here](https://kratzert.github.io/2017/02/24/finetuning-alexnet-with-tensorflow.html)

The data there has 1000 classes so it has weights according to that. How do I make it work for predicting values for my data that has 3 classes?

I know I have to change the weights but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

> add one more layer on top of the pre trained network

. This will be your

> output layer

.

This output of the 1000 class layer will be the input of this layer, and it will give your 3 classes as output.

After that train this new network with your images

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set `num_classes = 3` which will reduce the number of output classes for both the model output tensor and the separately defined placeholder `y`.

The number of weights, i.e. parameters, will be adapted accordingly when calling `model = AlexNet(...`.

Comment: I have done that and that gives me the accuracy. But when I try to predict a value using another image, it gives me an error because there are 1000 wights for the last layer I don't know how to change that.